# Are there any efficient 2D ArrayList classes for Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I know that it's possible to create a 2D ArrayList with `ArrayList<ArrayList<E>>`, but that is cumbersome and a real casting nightmare when it comes to adding and retrieving objects.

Are there any 2D ArrayList classes that do this sort of thing more efficiently? I am writing a true 2D ArrayList class from the ground up, and I'm wondering if there is anyone else who has done this sort of thing in an efficient manner.

Comment: What do you need more efficiency in?

Comment: Efficiency in general. There are pseudo 2D ArrayList classes that use LinkedLists, nested ArrayLists, or just plain multi-dimensional arrays, which can be horribly inefficient speed- and memory-wise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no, unfortunately there isn't 2d ArrayList class. your alternative options are (in case 0/1/2 of the Diamension is constant):

```
MyType[][] myList = new MyType[n][m];
```

or

```
ArrayList<MyType>[] myList = new ArrayList<MyType>[n];
```

or

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<MyType>> myList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<MyType>>();
```

another option is to save all your data in 1d ArrayList and create a function that recieve (x,y) and return the place x in the ArrayList. this way you demonstrate outside a 2d array, but save the elements easily in 1d ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

Using the "ArrayList>" type approach is fine and pretty standard for this kind of thing from what I have seen. You can easily write a 2D array list class that provides convenience methods for adding / removing items, etc, and it will be far from "cumbersome" or "a casting nightmare" to use this. Have a look at [this](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-code-snippets-tutorials/696-multi-dimension-arraylist-example.html) implementation as an example. It is not quite perfect but it illustrates how easy it is to use this kind of approach.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [FastTable](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/util/FastTable.html) in javolution and [Table](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) implementations in guava

Comment: links are  broken

Answer (score 0):

Google Collections has a Table collection. It's laid out as Rows/Cols and accesible directly, bycol, and by rows. Different implementations of Table have different efficiencies based on access type

Answer (score 0):

I built a 3D "grid" data structure, if it is any help.

- https://github.com/mikera/mikera/blob/master/src/main/java/mikera/engine/TreeGrid.java

The key trick is sub-dividing space into "blocks" so that sparse data can be efficiently stored.

You can use it as a 2D collection if you like by ignoring the z dimension (keeping it at 0), though that is probably a bit of overkill. Still, an option if you want this kind of structure. Alternatively, you could simplify it down to 2D.